# Camera Projection Displacement

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, displacement, volumetrics

I have been trying to recreate [this c4d/Arnold tutorial in blender](https://youtu.be/qakl3SI9whM)
and I'm stuck trying to Displace the mesh only in one direction (In the video the displacement is applied to the z axis. min 06:31).

[image]

Later in the video he creates a mapping camera for the displacement inside the Arnold node editor.
I was wondering if this can be achived using the **Vector Transform** node.

Here is [the blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CiXUpptSl7mvt3SMAqM2PcB-R437Vahl/view?usp=sharing) to show my progress on this. I hope that it helps. (I had to upload it to google drive because the file is too big for the stackerexchange server)

I hope that someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

One little detail that I want to say is that I'm using blender 2.79 daily build.

Comment: Instead of having users go through endless links just to understand your question, Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and explain what you want to do as part of the text. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand what you have done and what is failing.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Here I have changed the post, I hope that it clarifies what I'm trying to do and failing miserably